# Replace All '&' to 'And' with exceptions

Tags: python, regex

I learned regex all from scratch and have been struggling with this regex issue for a while and still haven't solved it.

Input:

```
exception_lst = ['r&b',
                 'm&a']
    
str_lst = ['fe r&b fe',
           'sar&bd',
           'sd r &B b',
           'as r& b ac',
           'sdf O&B sd',
           'df R&B sdc',
           's r&p es',
           'sf m & A df']
```

Expected Output:

```
str_lst = ['fe r&b fe',
           'sar and bd',
           'sd r&b b',
           'as r&b ac',
           'sdf O and B sd',
           'df R&B sdc',
           's r and p es',
           'sf m&a df']
```

What I want to achieve is

1. Change all & to ' and ' except the combinations in the exception list.
2. The exception list can be dynamically inputted.
3. The exception list is not case-sensitive.
4. Regex can still capture the exception if there are spaces in between. e.g. r & b and r& b are the same exception as r&b.
5. Regex can only identify the exception if it is surrounded by spaces. e.g. sar&bd is not an exception.

I tried several here, but none of them met all the requirements.

[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/phJ3Oa/1)

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/yNF0Dm/1)

Comment: It's not clear which of the test strings at the regex101 links you are expecting to be matched.

Comment: In two places you refer to "spaces". Does that mean one space (as in your examples) or any number of spaces? Do you want this done for the two literal "exceptions" `'r&b'` and `'m&a'` or for whatever happens to be in `exception_lst`? That you want `'sd r &B b'` converted to `'sd r&b b'` tells me you want to do more than just convert some `'&'` to `' and '`, meaning you cannot do what you want with a single regular expression. Please add a tag for the language you are using. Also, it's unlikely that anyone will be searching on the regex tags other than `regex`, so they can be removed.

Comment: Why did `'sd r &B b'` convert to `'sd r&B b'`? Or is that a typo?

Comment: I would do three steps: (1) change the `&`  in all the exceptional cases to something that does not occur anywhere else. (2) Change all the remaining `&` to `and`  plus the spaces. (3) Revert step (1), i.e. change them back to `&`.

Comment: One way is to use multiple lookbehinds and aheads inside [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/lsG9bm/1) (not beautiful). Better use [The Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick): *Match what you don't want but **capture** what you need* (what's remaining). Using it makes the regex easier to read, e.g. [`(?i)\b(?:r ?& ?b|m ?& ?a)\b|(&)`](https://regex101.com/r/z8zOkx/1) and use with lambda to check if `group(1)` is set. If set, return `and` else `group(0)` ([pyhton demo](https://ideone.com/fork/BeVVKI))

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following combined approach, which searches for rows that match one of the exceptions, and the matching ones are skipped, and the necessary replacement is performed in the non-matching ones.

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint

exception_lst = ['r&b', 'm&a']
    
str_lst = ['fe r&b fe',
           'sar&bd',
           'sd r &B b',
           'as r& b ac',
           'sdf O&B sd',
           'df R&B sdc',
           's r&p es',
           'sf m & A df']

res_lst = []

rxs = '|'.join((x.replace('&', r'\s*&\s*') for x in exception_lst))
rxs = fr'(?i)^.*\b(?:{rxs})\b'
rx = re.compile(rxs)
print(f'{rxs}\n\n')
for s in str_lst:
  res_lst.append(s.replace('&', ' and ') if not rx.match(s) else s)
pprint(res_lst)
```

Output.

```
(?i)^.*\b(?:r\s*&\s*b|m\s*&\s*a)\b

['fe r&b fe',
 'sar and bd',
 'sd r &B b',
 'as r& b ac',
 'sdf O and B sd',
 'df R&B sdc',
 's r and p es',
 'sf m & A df']
```

The regular expression obtained in this fragment can be broken down as follows.

```
(?i)  # set flags for this block (case-insensitive)
^     # the beginning of the string
.*    # any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
\b    # the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char
(?:   # group, but do not capture:
  r   #   'r'
  \s* #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  &   #   '&'
  \s* #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  b   #   'b'
 |    #  OR
  m   #   'm'
  \s* #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  &   #   '&'
  \s* #   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  a   #   'a'
)     # end of grouping
\b    # the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char
```

**Update.**

A fully regex solution.

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint

exception_lst = ['r&b', 'm&a']
    
str_lst = ['fe r&b fe',
           'sar&bd',
           'sd r &B b',
           'as r& b ac',
           'sdf O&B sd',
           'df R&B sdc',
           's r&p es',
           'sf m & A df',
           'I like to listen to r&b & techno while I work on M&A, you know?']

rxs = '|'.join((x.replace('&', r'\s*&\s*') for x in exception_lst))
rxs = fr'(?!\b(?:{rxs})\b)(\S)\s*&\s*(\S)'
rx = re.compile(rxs, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
print(f'{rxs}\n\n')
subs = '\\1 and \\2'
res_lst = [rx.sub(subs, s) for s in str_lst]
pprint(res_lst)
```

Output (a regex only).

```
(?!\b(?:r\s*&\s*b|m\s*&\s*a)\b)(\S)\s*&\s*(\S)

['fe r&b fe',
 'sar and bd',
 'sd r &B b',
 'as r& b ac',
 'sdf O and B sd',
 'df R&B sdc',
 's r and p es',
 'sf m & A df',
 'I like to listen to r&b and techno while I work on M&A, you know?']
```

Some explanation of the previous regex.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(?!      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b       the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    r        'r'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most
             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    &        '&'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most
             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    b        'b'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    m        'm'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most
             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    &        '&'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most
             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    a        'a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b       the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
)        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
)        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\s*      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most
         amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
&        '&'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\s*      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most
         amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
)        end of \2
```

Comment: Note that this approach is limited to simple cases like in OP's sample. It is unclear whether OP meant to include more complex cases with multiple matches and exceptions, like "I like to listen to r&b & techno while I work on M&A, you know?" (which can't be done in a single Python regex).

Comment: @Amadan, and yet I think a fully regex solution exists. Look at my updated update :)

Comment: Glad to have been proven wrong :)